# IntelliJ Embedded Java JVM plugin bash error

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea

I currently use IntelliJ with the Embedded Java JVM plugin so I can write code on my Mac and compile and run the Java program on my Raspberry Pi.

However, scanner isn't working or at least it thinks its a bash command.

[image: CLI program asking for menu option number using keyboard]

I'm not sure how to make it so that whenever I need to input something, it goes directly to the program. Here is my configuration:

[image]

Any ideas? I would hate to have to manually create a jar file from the project, and ssh it to the raspberry pi, and then run it from there.

Comment: Do you run this JVM remotely or locally?

Comment: Remotely. On my Mac I just simply write the code and the Embedded JVM plugin takes the code and runs it on the Raspberry Pi. But not sure why it thinks inputs are bash commands.

Comment: may be it's using a shell on the backend.

Comment: I'm not sure if the developer of this plugin has disclosed that. If it is then I guess there is nothing I could do at this point unless someone else here has encountered the same issue and has a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Eclipse with LaunchPI plugin. It allows me to enter information in the console while remote debugging which is what I needed.